# Bootstrap fixed footer smashing together with container div

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

If you zoom, the content in the container div smashes together with the fixed footer. And if I add more rows to the table in the center, the footer doesn't move down on the page, it smashes together.

There seems to be a fixed number of pixels between the navbar and footer - I would like the page to expand as far as I want and the footer to always be on the bottom.

I tried class="container-fluid" and class="row fluid" and neither fixed this problem. I also Googled and searched stackoverflow extensively and I can't find a solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move `<div id="footer">` inside the `<div class="container">`, just after the `div` of the table. Also, remove the `<div class="container">` that is inside the footer, it isn't necessary.

The result should be something similar to the image:

[image: Result]

**EDIT:** Also, if you want to make your footer sticky you can use this trick from [CSS-tricks](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/fixed-footer/).

```
#footer {
   position:fixed;
   left:0px;
   bottom:0px;
   height:50px;
   width:100%;
   background:#999;
}
```

And remember to increase the `margin-bottom` from the table.

Comment: Thanks. That fixes the smashing together, but the footer is no longer fixed. I want the footer fixed at the bottom of the page, as it was.

Comment: @wilfra I made some changes to the question to fix the footer at the bottom. I hope it helps =).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help - still getting some weird bugs though. It now fixed the footer at the bottom but it sucks some of the content into the footer. I tried moving the footer into different divs, also tried reducing content on the page. Same result. Will keep playing with it.